# NodeJS : Refactoring a long switch statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, switch-statement

I have a long **switch** statement and I need to replace it with more practice statement, any help please:

```
switch (global.testSuite) {
    case "cleanCache":
      testSenarios.cleanCache();
      break;
    case "setting":
      testSenarios.setting();
      break;
    case "installExtensions":
      testSenarios.installExtensions();
      break;
    case "addIndividualContact":
      testSenarios.addIndividualContact();
      break;
    case "addContact":
      testSenarios.addContact();
      break;
    case "add":
      testSenarios.add();
      break;
}
```

Comment: `testSenarios[global.testSuite]()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have only valid properties in `testSenarios`, you could make a check and call the function with brackets as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```
if (global.testSuite in testSenarios) {
     testSenarios[global.testSuite]();
}
```

Or if you have more properties without being a function, you might check for `function` instead.

```
if (typeof testSenarios[global.testSuite] === 'function') {
     testSenarios[global.testSuite]();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch case can easily be replaced with Object with key-value pairs.

```
//Define a object 
const testSuite = {
    cleanCache : testSenarios.cleanCache,
    setting : testSenarios.setting
    ......
    ....
}

//Then Replace the switch-case block with a single call
testSuite[global.testSuite]()
```

You can even add a 'default' key to handle the default case.

Comment: You are calling every single function while setting up your object, then not calling the function in your replacement line.